# How to use Laravel Directive Currency format in Blade with laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I have some textbox like this
`{{{ Form::number('amount', $cash->amount , array('class'=>'form-control')) }}}`
but I want to display the textbox in currency formatting

I have try to make Laravel directive like this
`Blade::directive('convert', function ($money) { return "<?php echo 'Rp.' . number_format($money, 2); ?>"; });`

and when I try in textbox `{{{ Form::number('amount', @convert($cash->amount) , array('class'=>'form-control')) }}}` that return parse error unexpected '<'
and the I'm trying to call the convert in label but that's error too.
and when I'm not using variabel, just doing like this
`<label>@convert(11223344)</label>`
that's work.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
{{{ Form::number('amount', 'Rp.' . number_format($cash->amount, 2), array('class'=>'form-control')) }}}
```

Comment: aw, taht's not error, but the value not showing. in console i see the warning ``The specified value "1,000,000.00" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.``

Comment: Firstly, can you remove the `'Rp.' .` from the code above and try again. I forgot this is a number input type.

Comment: I already delete the Rp. , but same error.